# Проверка наличия элемента в массиве строк

Tags: java, массивы

Есть метод, который проверяет наличие элемента в массиве:

```
private boolean existA(String a) {
    for (String s : massStringA) {
        if (a.equals(s)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

---

Является ли этот метод оптимальным, или же это "велосипед", и существует более оптимальное решение этой задачи?

Comment: Массив сортирован? Можно ли его отсортировать?

Comment: Массив не отсортирован, порядок его элементов не имеет значения

Comment: Юзайте, то что написали, это нормальное решение, для массива из <= 15 элементов.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Если не касаться вопроса сортировки, то более короткой формой будет

```
return Arrays.asList(massStringA).contains(s);
```

(заметьте, `Arrays.asList()` не создаёт копию массива, а использует оригинал, так что это не удваивает расход памяти).

Answer (score 2):

Если массив может быть отсортирован, то тогда можно ускорить механизм поиска.

```
String[] massStringA = ...;

// массив будет изменен!
Arrays.sort(massStringA);
if(Arrays.binarySearch(massStringA, a) >= 0) {
    // строка найдена
};
```

Если массив нельзя изменять и используется Java 8, то можно применить Stream

```
if(Arrays.stream(massStringA).anyMatch(s -> s.equals(a))) {
    // строка найдена
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Более оптимальное решение - скопировать `String[]` в `HashSet<String>`, после чего использовать метод `contains` у `HashSet`.

Сделал искусственный пример. Возможно, на реальных данных результаты будут отличаться.

```
private static final int
        STRINGS_COUNT = 100 * 1000,
        TESTS_COUNT = 100 * 1000;

private static final HashSet<String> hashSet = new HashSet<>();
private static final String[] massStringA = new String[STRINGS_COUNT];

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < STRINGS_COUNT; i++)
    {
        massStringA[i] = createString(i);
    }

    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    hashSet.addAll(Arrays.asList(massStringA));
    System.out.println("Copy time: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime) + "ms");

    Random rand = new Random();
    String[] testStrings = new String[TESTS_COUNT];
    for (int i = 0; i < TESTS_COUNT; i++)
    {
        int randValue = rand.nextInt(STRINGS_COUNT * 10);
        testStrings[i] = createString(randValue);
    }

    startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    int matches = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < TESTS_COUNT; i++)
    {
        if (existA(testStrings[i]))
        {
            matches++;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Array search time: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime) + "ms, matches: " + matches);

    startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    matches = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < TESTS_COUNT; i++)
    {
        if (Arrays.asList(massStringA).contains(testStrings[i]))
        {
            matches++;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Arrays.asList search time: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime) + "ms, matches: " + matches);

    startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    matches = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < TESTS_COUNT; i++)
    {
        if (hashSet.contains(testStrings[i]))
        {
            matches++;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("HashSet search time: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime) + "ms, matches: " + matches);
}

private static String createString(int number)
{
    int value = number;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    while (value > 0)
    {
        sb.append((char)(value % 80 + 47));
        value /= 80;
    }
    return sb.toString();
}

private static boolean existA(String a)
{
    for (String s : massStringA)
    {
        if (a.equals(s))
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Для 100 тысяч тестов при 100 тысячах строк результаты такие:

```
Copy time: 16ms
Array search time: 69762ms, matches: 9858
Arrays.asList search time: 73248ms, matches: 9858
HashSet search time: 14ms, matches: 9858
```

Для миллиона тестов при 10 тысячах строк:

```
Copy time: 3ms
Array search time: 17775ms, matches: 99845
Arrays.asList search time: 17537ms, matches: 99845
HashSet search time: 26ms, matches: 99845
```

Comment: Почему бы не использовать ```Set``` вместо ```Map```?

Comment: @temq дурацкая привычка использовать `HashMap` там, где больше подходит `HashSet` или `TreeMap`. Изменил на `HashSet`, спасибо.

Comment: Все зависит сильно от использования метода. Если автор юзает его редко, то смысла копировать в hashset нет, мы только добьемся увеличения оверхеда по памяти и ухудшения локальности данных.  Если массив сравнительно не большой, то простая итерация и сравнение является пожалуй оптимальным решением.

Comment: Спасибо Вам большое за такой кропотливый труд, и за статистику.   В примере используется небольшой массив строк < 15 элементов

Comment: @ArtemKonovalov если элементов в массиве мало (меньше 15 элементов, как выше выяснилось), то можно хоть за `O(n^4)` искать - ничего не поменяется: речь будет про пару ms. Вопрос в таком случае (а в нём был упор на оптимальность) лишен всякого смысла.

Comment: вопрос был задан, чтобы выяснить, существует ли стандарнтый способ решения этой задачи. Например: зачем мне писать свой метод сортировки, если есть метод `sort` (подразумевается, что я о нем не знаю)

Answer (score -3):

Можно использовать метод `contains`

> public boolean contains(CharSequence s)

Вот пример проверки наличия строки `"abc"` в строке `"abcdgd;aoihvfsl"`:

```
String string = "abcdgd;aoihvfsl";
if (string.contains(String.valueOf("abc"))
```

В данном случае возвратит `true`.

Comment: Вопрос про массив, а не про строку.